# What does mean double @ in a class Name Html element?

Tags: html, css

I've been wondering what does the following mean

```
<li class="navigation__sub navigation__sub--active navigation__sub--toggled">
         <a href="default.htm"><i class="zmdi zmdi-view-list"></i> Table</a>

         <ul>
               <li class="navigation__active"><a href="html-table.html">HTML Table</a></li>
               <li class="@@datatableactive"><a href="data-table.html">Data Table</a></li>
         </ul>
</li>
```

What does a_class name with double @  mean?  In li element the class name @@datatableactive what does mean?

Comment: Is that what gets sent to browser or is there a templating script involved that replaces it?

Comment: There is no mention of `@@ class name` rule mentioned in the the CSS specs (https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#class-html), so I can only think of it as a custom naming convention that is used in JavaScript or automated tests (BDD selector). If neither of those apply, this is just a weirdly named class selector.